# Mostrar en formato JSON un objeto en Vuejs

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, vue.js

como hago para mostrar una lista en este caso `dataItems` en formato `JSON`.
Necesito mostrar un lista que se edita en el DOM y no la que ya este almacenada en la base de datos.

script completo:

```
<template>
  <div >
   <div class="container">
        <button class="button is-primary is-small" @click="addNode">
            <span class="icon is-small" style="margin-right: 2px;">
                <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
            </span>
            Nuevo Treeno
        </button>
        <vue-tree-list 
        @click="onClick" 
        :model="dataItems" 
        v-model="dataModel"
        default-tree-node-name="new node" 
        default-leaf-node-name="new leaf">
        </vue-tree-list>
    </div>
<div> {{ dataModel }}</div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="has-text-centered" style="margin-bottom: 1rem">
        <button class="button is-primary" type="button" name="button" @click="getNewTree">Get New Tree</button>
      </div>
      <pre>
        {{newTree}}
      </pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>



    <script>

   window.VueTreeList = require('../../../public/js/dist/vue-tree-list.js')



      function isMobile() {
        var sUserAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

        var bIsIpad = /ipad/i.test(sUserAgent);
        var bIsIphoneOs = /iphone os/i.test(sUserAgent);
        var bIsMidp = /midp/i.test(sUserAgent);
        var bIsUc7 = /rv:1.2.3.4/i.test(sUserAgent);
        var bIsUc = /ucweb/i.test(sUserAgent);
        var bIsAndroid = /android/i.test(sUserAgent);
        var bIsCE = /windows ce/i.test(sUserAgent);
        var bIsWM = /windows mobile/i.test(sUserAgent);
        var bIsWx = /MicroMessenger/i.test(sUserAgent);
        if (bIsIpad || bIsIphoneOs || bIsMidp || bIsUc7 || bIsUc || bIsAndroid || bIsCE || bIsWM || bIsWx) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }

    export default {
      props:{

      },
        components: {
          'VueTreeList': VueTreeList.VueTreeList
        },
        data () {
          return {
            isMobile: isMobile(),
            record: null,
            newTree: {},
            dataItems:{},
            dataModel:[],
            data: new VueTreeList.Tree([
              {
                name: 'Node 13',
                id: 1,
                pid: 0,
                dragDisabled: true,
                children: [
                  {
                    name: 'Node 1-2',
                    id: 2,
                    isLeaf: false,
                    pid: 1
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                name: 'Node 23',
                id: 3,
                pid: 0,
                disabled: true
              },
              {
                name: 'Node 34',
                id: 4,
                pid: 0
              }
            ])
          }
        },
        created: function(){
            this.getPlan();
        },
        methods: {
          getTreeChange: function () {
            this.record = Object.assign({}, VueTreeList.Record)
          },
          getPlan() {
          const dev = this;
          let uri = "http://localhost/software/program/public/datajson";
          axios
            .get(uri, {
              method: "GET",
              mode: "no-cors",
              headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
              },
              withCredentials: true,
              credentials: "same-origin"
            })
            .then(response => {
              dev.dataItems = new VueTreeList.Tree(response.data);
              dev.dataModel = response.json();
              console.log(Object.keys(dev.dataItems).length)

            });
        },
          addNode: function () {
            var node = new VueTreeList.TreeNode({ name: 'Nuevo node', isLeaf: false })
            if (!this.data.children) this.data.children = []
            this.data.addChildren(node)
            console.log('datos console')
          },


      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Les dejo la solcion por alguno le interesa:

```
MostrarJSON: function () {
                var vm = this
                function _dfs (oldNode) {
                  var newNode = {}

                  for (var k in oldNode) {
                    if (k !== 'children' && k !== 'parent') {
                      newNode[k] = oldNode[k]
                    }
                  }

                  if (oldNode.children && oldNode.children.length > 0) {
                    newNode.children = []
                    for (var i = 0, len = oldNode.children.length; i < len; i++) {
                      newNode.children.push(_dfs(oldNode.children[i]))
                    }
                  }
                  return newNode
                }

                vm.newTree = _dfs(vm.dataItems)
              }
```